# IntelliJ showing an -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 message

Tags: java, intellij-idea, encoding, utf-8

I have a clean installation of IntelliJ on macOS, however everytime I run a project I get the following message when it starts:

> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
>   "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA
>   CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=50269:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA
>   CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath
>   /Users/armando/Desktop/CodigoJava/out/production/CodigoJava
>   com.picoegallo.Main

I have checked every single encoding option but I cannot get rid of this, any idea on how it can be fixed?

Thanks!

Comment: There is related request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-172607